# How to avoid to resend data and update page in django forms?

Tags: python, django, forms, redirect

I have a modal form which is displayed clicking some buttons.
When the user fill the form and submit it i can save the data and redirect the user to and index page.
If the user return on the previous page he see the "old" form already filled, because the page isn't refreshed. What can i  do?

This is my wiew:

```
def calendar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = ReservationForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        print('prima del form valid')
        if form.is_valid():
            print("il form e' valido")
            reservation = form.save(commit=False)
            reservation.validation_code = get_random_string(length=32)
            reservation.delete_code = get_random_string(length=8).upper()
            reservation.reservation_confirmed = False
            reservation.save()
            return redirect('prenotazionicampo:index')
            # return render(request, 'prenotazionicampo/index.html')
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = ReservationForm()
```

Comment: by 'return' do you mean the user clicks the 'back' button?

Comment: Yes! The 'back' button of the browser

Answer (score 1):

In the form in your HTML template, add `<form autocomplete="off" ...>`. This should be able to fix your problem.